# Is there any full integrated Rails gemset available for download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Because I'm behind a proxy at work that makes it quite impossible to easily install rubygems I'm curious whether there is a possibility to download a "self contained" gemset with all dependencies already included?

I know about the BitNami Infrastructure and Application Stacks which are quite good but are little bit too much. I just want the gems and not a MySQL server, HTTP server, whatever...

After some resultless research through the internet I hope someone here has an answer for me.

Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7934109/1056102) similar question might help you.

Comment: So I think using Bundler is the only solution.